# Static char allocates more disk memory then static integer

Tags: c, static, allocation

I wrote empty program and i compiled it.
It allocated 12.456 bytes of disk memory.

[image]

Then i added static integer, and the size increased by 32 bytes (the size is now 12.488 bytes). But when i added static char the size increased by 40 bytes. How come static char allocates more disk memory than static int?

Edit:

I run GNU Compiler on x86_64 machine.
Here's the source,

```
int
main(void) {

}
```

Allocates: 12456 B of disk memory.

```
int
main(void) {
    static int int1;
}
```

Allocates: 12488 bytes (+32 B)

```
int
main(void) {
    static int int1;
    static char char1;
}
```

Allocates: 12528 bytes (+40 B)

Comment: If the source code is not too big. Can you share it? I would like to have a look at it

Comment: This is not a pure C question, but a C + <compiler> + <platform> question. I can guess what those are, but you should add tags (and possibly provide the source of your program) to clarify and avoid bad assumptions.

Comment: "If the source code is not too big"? It's right there in front of you, some twenty bytes :-) I think we could handle that (unless it's `#include "bigfile"`).

Comment: Hm, let's see... 40/32 = 5/4, and `sizeof({'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', '\0'}) == 5` and `sizeof({'i', 'n', 't', '\0'}) == 4`... did the Illuminati send you that code?

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan There i edited it.

Comment: @GManNickG I use GNU compliler on x86_64

Comment: @KerrekSB lol i clarified it. sorry

Comment: Why do you think the size of the extra `int` makes  sense? An `int` is **32 Bits = 4 Bytes** large, not **32 Bytes**...

Comment: Take a look at what the `size` command says about the sizes. There is more information in the file than you're thinking.

Comment: Block-scope static variables may also require an initialization flag and mutex.

Answer (score 3):

Because the names of the variables are stored in the binary for debugging purposes. Presumably you compiled with `-g` or your compiler automatically inserts debugging symbols if you don't optimize. If you look at the binaries with a hex editor, you can see this.

Here's the end of the first program with no variables. The first column is the hex position in the file. The next eight are the hex values in the file. And the last column is its ASCII representation. This is done using [emacs hexl-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HexlMode). The details will vary, this is on OS X with `clang -g`.

```
000010e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5f5f 6d68 5f65  ........ .__mh_e
000010f0: 7865 6375 7465 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f6d  xecute_header._m
00001100: 6169 6e00 6479 6c64 5f73 7475 625f 6269  ain.dyld_stub_bi
00001110: 6e64 6572 002f 5573 6572 732f 7363 6877  nder./Users/schw
00001120: 6572 6e2f 746d 702f 0074 6573 742e 6300  ern/tmp/.test.c.
00001130: 2f76 6172 2f66 6f6c 6465 7273 2f30 622f  /var/folders/0b/
00001140: 3778 7032 6c78 6264 3779 6c30 7463 706d  7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpm
00001150: 7330 3666 7233 6434 3030 3030 676e 2f54  s06fr3d40000gn/T
00001160: 2f74 6573 742d 6439 6332 6233 2e6f 005f  /test-d9c2b3.o._
00001170: 6d61 696e 0000 0000                      main....
```

Here's the second with just `int1`.

```
00002100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5f5f 6d68 5f65  ........ .__mh_e
00002110: 7865 6375 7465 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f6d  xecute_header._m
00002120: 6169 6e00 6479 6c64 5f73 7475 625f 6269  ain.dyld_stub_bi
00002130: 6e64 6572 002f 5573 6572 732f 7363 6877  nder./Users/schw
00002140: 6572 6e2f 746d 702f 0074 6573 742e 6300  ern/tmp/.test.c.
00002150: 2f76 6172 2f66 6f6c 6465 7273 2f30 622f  /var/folders/0b/
00002160: 3778 7032 6c78 6264 3779 6c30 7463 706d  7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpm
00002170: 7330 3666 7233 6434 3030 3030 676e 2f54  s06fr3d40000gn/T
00002180: 2f74 6573 742d 3136 6564 3035 2e6f 005f  /test-16ed05.o._
00002190: 6d61 696e 005f 6d61 696e 2e69 6e74 3100  main._main.int1.
000021a0: 5f6d 6169 6e2e 696e 7431 0000 0000 0000  _main.int1......
```

And here's the third with `int1` and `char1`.

```
00002120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5f5f 6d68 5f65  ........ .__mh_e
00002130: 7865 6375 7465 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f6d  xecute_header._m
00002140: 6169 6e00 6479 6c64 5f73 7475 625f 6269  ain.dyld_stub_bi
00002150: 6e64 6572 002f 5573 6572 732f 7363 6877  nder./Users/schw
00002160: 6572 6e2f 746d 702f 0074 6573 742e 6300  ern/tmp/.test.c.
00002170: 2f76 6172 2f66 6f6c 6465 7273 2f30 622f  /var/folders/0b/
00002180: 3778 7032 6c78 6264 3779 6c30 7463 706d  7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpm
00002190: 7330 3666 7233 6434 3030 3030 676e 2f54  s06fr3d40000gn/T
000021a0: 2f74 6573 742d 3036 3865 3366 2e6f 005f  /test-068e3f.o._
000021b0: 6d61 696e 005f 6d61 696e 2e69 6e74 3100  main._main.int1.
000021c0: 5f6d 6169 6e2e 6368 6172 3100 5f6d 6169  _main.char1._mai
000021d0: 6e2e 696e 7431 005f 6d61 696e 2e63 6861  n.int1._main.cha
000021e0: 7231 0000 0000 0000                      r1......
```

Without `-g` and no optimization flags at all, I get a similar, but less wordy, result.

```
00002080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5f5f 6d68 5f65  ........ .__mh_e
00002090: 7865 6375 7465 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f6d  xecute_header._m
000020a0: 6169 6e00 6479 6c64 5f73 7475 625f 6269  ain.dyld_stub_bi
000020b0: 6e64 6572 005f 6d61 696e 2e69 6e74 3100  nder._main.int1.
000020c0: 5f6d 6169 6e2e 6368 6172 3100 0000 0000  _main.char1.....
```

If I compile without `-g` and with `-O` for optimizations, there will be no symbols both because the compiler will not retain variable names for debugging, and also because the optimizer will remove the unused variables.

```
00001060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 5f5f 6d68 5f65  ........ .__mh_e
00001070: 7865 6375 7465 5f68 6561 6465 7200 5f6d  xecute_header._m
00001080: 6169 6e00 6479 6c64 5f73 7475 625f 6269  ain.dyld_stub_bi
00001090: 6e64 6572 0000 0000                      nder....
```

All three programs are equivalent and produce exactly the same binaries using `clang -O`. I assume `gcc` will act the same.